# Log4Net does not log when Process is initiated through another application

Tags: c#, log4net

I have two applications(**A** and **B**). **A** instantiates **B** using Process.Start(). Both use log4net to log data to two different XML files(**File1** and **File2**).

> When **B** is instantiated directly it logs to the file. But When it
>   is instantiated through **A**, it does not log information to the file.

Following is my configuration:

```
<log4net>
    <logger name="A.Program" additivity="true">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="ARollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="B.Program" additivity="true">
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="BRollingFileAppender"/>
    </logger>

    <appender name="ARollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs/File1.xml"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
        <locationInfo value="true"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="BRollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="logs/File2.xml"/>
      <appendToFile value="true"/>
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
      <rollingStyle value="Size"/>
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.XmlLayoutSchemaLog4j">
        <locationInfo value="true"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>    
  </log4net>
```

I have tried to perform log4net debug of **B** after it is instantiated by **A**. It shows the following with no errors:

**log4net: Opening file for writing [** File2 s location **] append [True]**

But when I check File2 at the same location, it does not have any logs written.

Comment: Is the log4net in the app/web config or a stand-alone file? If the former, is it in both applications? Also, how are you configuring log4net, using XmlConfigurator or an assembly attribute?

Comment: It is in a stand alone file. To configure I use assembly attribute: [assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(Watch = true, ConfigFile = "Configuration/CLogging.Config.xml", ConfigFileExtension = "xml")]

        private static readonly log4net.ILog logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

Comment: Did you find a solution for this one? I got the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
```

to the appenders. This will do a minimal lock on the file. However this will impact your performance if you do log a lot. In that case it would be better to give each application its own log file.

However if you want each application to log to its own log file, you can also remove the appenders of the other application from your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

> To configure I use assembly attribute…

I suspect that is your problem. You don't specify whether the attribute is defined in Project A or Project B (or both) but note this from [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#attributes):

> Using attributes can be a clearer method for defining where the application's configuration will be loaded from.
>
> However it is worth noting that attributes are purely passive. They are information only.
>
> Therefore if you use configuration attributes you must invoke log4net to allow it to read the attributes. A simple call to `LogManager.GetLogger` will cause the attributes on the calling assembly to be read and processed.
>
> **Therefore it is imperative to make a logging call as early as possible during the application start-up, and certainly before any external assemblies have been loaded and invoked.**

In this situation it would be easier to use XmlConfiguration instead.